# Docker Containers NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I am on CentOS-8 and have a couple of spring-boot services: demo-client calls demo-server over HTTP through spring RestTemplate. This works fine without Docker container.
But when I deploy them as docker-compose with default network, demo-client is not able to call demo-server. I tried with service-name and also with ip-address of the container but same error in both cases:

```
demo-client_1  | 2020-02-29 10:23:55.165 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: **I/O error on GET request for "http://172.24.0.2:8081/hello": Host is unreachable (Host unreachable);** nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable (Host unreachable)] with root cause
demo-client_1  | 
demo-client_1  | java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable (Host unreachable)
demo-client_1  |    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
demo-client_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]*
```

Docker compose file :

```
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  demo-client:
    build: ./demo-client
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - demo-server
  demo-server:
    build: ./demo-server
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

I tried following firewall related actions as suggested in some of the earlier posts:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --reload
service firewalld restart*
```

None of this worked. What I thought to be a straight forward thing turned out to be more complex.

Comment: Before playing with firewall, reset it to their defaults and  try to narrow the possibilities. Connect to the client app and ping the app, then try to curl that. Connect to it with  `docker exec -ti YOUR_CONTAINER sh` .

Comment: You should be able to connect from `demo-client` to `demo-server`, using `demo-server` as a host name; you should not need to change that `docker-compose.yml` or change your host firewall settings.  Also double-check that the server is listening on 0.0.0.0:8081 ("all interfaces") and not 127.0.0.1:8081 ("the container-private localhost interface only").

Comment: @DavidMaze
How do I check this:
Also double-check that the server is listening on 0.0.0.0:8081 ("all interfaces") and not 127.0.0.1:8081 ("the container-private localhost interface only"). 

*** I see this in "docker ps" result:

a64a617f0841        explore_demo-client   "java -jar /app.jar"   8 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp   explore_demo-client_1
2ae0a4e75933        explore_demo-server   "java -jar /app.jar"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   explore_demo-server_1

Comment: @davidxxx: Hi, I am able to ping the two containers from each other: 

<code>[user@localhost explore]$ docker exec -ti 88a10e840cf0 sh '/ # ping demo-server PING demo-server (172.27.0.2): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 172.27.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.137 ms</code> 
<code>[user@localhost explore]$ docker exec -ti fcad3882f0e3 sh / # ping demo-client PING demo-client (172.27.0.3): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 172.27.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms 64 bytes from 172.27.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms</code>

Comment: I am getting same error when I curl it:

/ # curl demo-server:8081/hello
curl: (7) Failed to connect to demo-server port 8081: Host is unreachable

Comment: @Hamid So to summarize, the two containers may communicate each other (which makes sense with default network created by docker compose)  but the communication to a specific port fail. That looks weird. I made that docker-compose setup multiple times with Spring micro services and it never causes that kind of issue.  Try to restart from zero : `docker-compose down`. Ensure that Ensure that the docker networks for the docker-compose are well  removed. Then do : `docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate`.  If it doesn't work, try to clean the docker objects more deeply.

Comment: @davidxxx Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but same result. I also reinstalled Docker and yet same issue. The thing which flagged is that CentOS-8 introduced Podman as official container tool instead of Docker and I used the instructions mentioned here(https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-docker-ce-centos-8-rhel-8/) to install it. 
May be Ill try with CentOS-7

Comment: This seems like an issue with CentOS-8. The same code worked fine with CentOS-7.

Comment: @Hamid - I have a web app container + postgres container, both spun up with docker-compose, yml file is standard. It works fine with Centos 7, but when using Centos 8, I have the same issues as above when trying to psql from the web app container to the postgres container., "could not connect to server: Host is unreachable"

Comment: @rnoodle - I was exploring Centos-8 and for now moved back to Centos-7. Centos-8 supports Podman and that's what they would focus on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Centos-8 and The same code worked fine with CentOS-7. so, for now I moved back to Centos-7.
CentOS-8 introduced Podman as official container tool instead of Docker

Answer (score 1):

In my case firewall blocking elastic port from the container. I stopped the firewall and restarted the application it worked.